# The method add(String) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Map)

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm really just a visual web designer and I manage to make some functional coding by getting some resources off the web. All I really need to do is show a list of training schedules in html via jsp from an array. I've been searching and been trying some "methods" and the I found below code as I believe the simplest to do.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Map course1 = new HashMap();
course1.put("code", "ME101");
course1.put("desc", "Marine Engineering 101");
course1.put("sched", "June 1 - August 30, 2014");
course1.put("rsvd", "56");
list.add(course1);

Map course2 = new HashMap();
course2.put("code", "ME102");
course2.put("desc", "Marine Engineering 102");
course2.put("sched", "September 1 - November 31, 2014");
course2.put("rsvd", "25");
list.add(course2);

Map course3 = new HashMap();
course3.put("code", "CSM101");
course3.put("desc", "Certificate on Seamanship 101");
course3.put("sched", "June 1 - June 30, 2014");
course3.put("rsvd", "36");
list.add(course3);  

pageContext.setAttribute("courses", list);
```

In the html part, I have these to display the values:

```
<c:forEach items="${courses}" var="current">
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${current.code}" /><td>
    <td><c:out value="${current.desc}" /><td>
    <td><c:out value="${current.sched}" /><td>
    <td><c:out value="${current.rsvd}" /><td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is these produces an error

> "The method add(String) in the type List is not applicable for
>   the arguments (Map)"

Could anyone help me how to make this work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your list as a list of strings:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But you try to add instances of Map to this List:

```
Map course1 = new HashMap();
...
list.add(course1);
```

A List of strings can only accept strings, not maps. If you want a list of maps, it should be defined as

```
List<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();
```

Note that your maps themselves should be strong-typed:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
...
Map<String, String> course1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
course1.put("code", "ME101");
```

Comment: Wow, that little change in the type did it. Thanks a lot! I guess I need to do some reading about the differences.